# Why is this hover addClass not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, addclass

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#box').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('fullColor');
    });
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#box {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:blue;
    opacity:0.5;
}

.fullColor {
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPW6c/

Comment: Looks like a click function, and not hover ?

Comment: It's about css specificity.

Comment: If you want it in hover-state, you should also consider changing `$('#box').hover()` not `.click()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `addClass` works, it's just that the browser decides that the opacity in `fullColor` is overwritten by that in `#box`.

If you change the declaration to:

```
#box.fullColor {
    opacity:1.0;
}
```

it will apply the new opacity.

In CCS the more specific rule wins. `#box` is more specific than `.fullColor` since ids are more specific than classes. And `#box.fullColor` has both the class and the id so it's more specific than `#box` and `.fullColor`.

Answer (score 2):

The class is correctly added. (This can/*should* have been verified using an appropriate developer tool.. which would also have shown which rules were applied, and why.)

However, the `#box` rule will *always* win over `.fullColor` due to [*CSS specificity*](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/):

> Specificity is a type of weighting that has a bearing on how your cascading style sheet (CSS) rules are displayed .. *If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.*

Use `#box.fullColor` as a selector and observe the result - it is "more specific" than just `#box`, although it is only applied when the `.fullColor` class is present, and will thus win.

If this is not possible (it does sometimes happen), then `!important` can be used, but such use should be done sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

A less elegant solution, if you need to keep those CSS values, is adding **!important** to the fullColor opacity:

```
.fullColor{
    opacity:1.0 !important;
 }
```